# Java Applets on local machines get AccessControlExceptions which depend on the code path

Tags: java, windows, security, applet

When I run my html page from the local directory E:/ForSteven/PDBModels/pages/2FFU.html
it works properly when I place the applet jar files with the html and say codebase="."

It also works when the pages are in a subdirectory of the jarfiles - say the code is at
E:/applet/code the page is in E:/applet/code/pages and the data is in  E:/applet/code/data -
that is both page and data are subdirectories of the code and codebase=".." and the file is ../data/mydata.txt

However if the code is in E:/applet/code , the page is in E:/applet/pages and the data is in
E:/applet/data and the codebase="../code"

then I get

### java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission E:\applet\data\data/mydata.txt read)

I am on a Windows 7 box my applet tag looks like this

```
<applet name="flash" code="JmolApplet" archive="JmolApplet.jar"
    codebase="../code"
    width="500" height="420" align="center" mayscript="true">
 ...
```

Comment: Given all the `File` paths, why use an applet at all?  An application with no security manager would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

please read [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Unsigned applets cannot perform the following operations:

- They cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem, executable files, system clipboard, and printers.
- They cannot connect to or retrieve resources from any third party server (any server other than the server it originated from).
- They cannot load native libraries.
- They cannot change the SecurityManager.
- They cannot create a ClassLoader.
- They cannot read certain system properties. See [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/properties.html) for a list of forbidden system properties.